# returning LINQ query in public action result

Tags: mysql, sql, linq, controller

I am trying to return database data from my controller, however I am not sure how I go about writing this LINQ statement so that it returns what I am looking for.
I have managed to return the following query, but only because it is getting data from one table:

```
public ActionResult GetChart()
        {
            return Json(db.Submission.Select(p => new { p.Title, p.Status }),
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

SO the above table works fine, I am now trying to use a query that uses two tables. How would I go about writing this part:

```
public ActionResult GetChart3()
        {
                         return Json(var result = from r in Researcher
                         join rs in ResearcherSubmission on r.ResearcherID equals rs.ResearcherID
                         join s in Submission on rs.SubmissionID equals s.SubmissionID
                         group r by new { r.FirstName, r.Surname } into g
                         select new
                         {
                             Name = g.Key.FirstName + " " + g.Key.Surname,
                             NumberofSubmissions = g.Count()
                         });
        }
```

Comment: Try using `.Join()`, then use `.Select()` at the end.

Comment: I am very new to LINQ. do you mind elaborating please

Comment: at the moment the GetChart3() code causes a few errors. so im  not sure what needs to be changed

Comment: what errors are you getting?